# Ember-data store PUT request

Tags: rest, datastore, ember-data

Is there any way to include the 'has many' models in the 'put' request sent using ember data-store REST adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You can have embedded records by defining them on the adapter

```
Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  votes: DS.hasMany(Vote)
});

Adapter.map(Comment, {
  votes: { embedded: 'always' }
});
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/embedded/embedded_dirtying_test.js#L53